# Why we are creating variable of type of class?

Tags: java

First Line we can use for create object, in which scenario we can use 2 and 3?

1. Test test =new Test();
2. Test test =null;
3. Test test ;

Comment: which book you are referring to learn Java?

Comment: None of  books explaining the above scenario...

Answer (score 2):

The first way actually creates an instance called Test and assigns it to the variable test.

```
Test test =new Test(); // ' ; ' missing
```

The second only assigns a null pointer to test.

```
Test test =null;
```

The third way does not assign anything to test, unless it is an instance variable in which case it will assign a value of null to it.

```
Test test ;
```

Answer (score 2):

You clearly don't "know" the following "ways" to create an object, since only one of your "ways" actually does (assuming the proper semicolon is added to allow the line to compile).

```
Test test = new Test();
```

That is the only way to actually create an object in direct Java syntax.  Object creation can be obfuscated by methods that use the new keyword behind the scenes, but it boils down to using the new keyword and a constructor invocation.

```
Test test = null;
```

Setting this variable to null doesn't create anything but a holder for a Test object named test.  But null is not an object and nothing is created.

```
Test test;
```

This line does the same thing as setting test to null in a class, but in a method it allows the declaration for the holder to allow it to be set in another line further down.  However, you will get a syntax error if the Java compiler can't figure out a path that you actually set this variable prior to it being read in further code.  To get around this error, you can set it to null at the beginning like the previous line.

Answer (score 0):

```
Test test;
```

in this case , didn't make object. this only create test variable in stack. it is Type is Test object type.

```
Test test=null;
```

in this case you assign null value to that referens.

```
Test test =new Test();
```

this mean ,you crate new object in class Test.this object made in heap.

I think this is basic thing  java. you do further research.
thank you.

Answer (score 0):

```
  public class Test{
    int a ;

    public Test(){
    }

    public class Test(int a){
        this.a = a ;
    }

    public static void main(String args[]){
        //To define a variable of type Test
        Test t ;
        //Defining another variable of type Test
        Test t2;

        //To instantiate an object of type Test using no argument constructor
        //Now t holds a reference to object created by new Test()
        t = new Test();

        //Pass the Object reference in t to t2 variable
        t2 = t ;

        //To instantiate an object using one argument constructor Test(int a)
        //Now t will hold reference to object created by new Test( 2)
        //That makes old Test instance created by no argument constructor eligible to be cleanedup by garbage collector
        t= new Test(2);

        //now to release the reference to object created by new Test(2) , we set null
        //In better words, we are setting the reference to "null", so that variable t no longer point to the test instance"
        //For better understanding, search for database/JDBC programming example to see how we use "null" in finally block
        t = null;
    }
```

Generally null is used to dereference any of the objects referenced by the particular variable.

Comment: Your documentation is incorrect on the "release" line.  Consider the following edit:  Test t2 = t;  t = null;

Comment: Ok, Metroid :) I just wanted to make him understand that constructor method is used along with new to create objects in Java ( in most of the OOPS languages ) and null is for dereferencing. Btw I am a newbie and confused where I went wrong. Why do we need T2 ? ( PS: I know I do lot of silly mistakes and will be happy to correct me)

Comment: It's splitting hairs, really, but someone may read that as "releasing the memory" rather than "setting the reference to no longer point to the test instance".  Technically you "released the reference" to "new Test()" as well, but you didn't document that.  I jumped the gun there, apologies.

Comment: No need of apologies bro, I know you just wanted to make my post better. I will correct mine. Thanks and Good day